# Show a continuous non-surjective map from a sphere to itself has a fixed point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f$ be a continuous and non surjective map from $S^2$ to $S^2$. Show that $f$ has a fixed point.

I've tried to use the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem, but I don't know how to transform the (first) sphere into a *disc*.

Comment: You don't transform the first sphere into a disc. You start with two discs, apply the BFP theorem, then make the discs into spheres and translate the results of the theorem to the new spaces.

Comment: @Welcome to Math.SE. The question in your title is missing the (crucial!) "non-surjective" hypothesis, and therefore differs from the question in the body of your post. When you get the chance, could you please edit your question title? :)

Answer (score 6):

Let $p$ be a point not in $f(S^2)$, and let $U$ be an open ball that contains $p$ and does not intersect $f(S^2)$. Then $f$ maps $X = S^2 \setminus U$ to itself. Since $X$ is homeomorphic to a disc, it follows from Brouwer's fixed-point theorem that (the restriction of) $f$ has a fixed point.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand why should such U exist?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the only reason to suspect such a U would exist is if $X\setminus f(S^2)$ is an open set, which I don't think it has to be. Or at least it's not clear to me why it has to be. Also I don't see why f should restrict to the identity map of $S^2\setminus U$.

Comment: @user1236:  Since $S^2$ is compact, $f(S^2)$ is also compact, so closed.  Thus, the complement is is open.  By hypothesis, $p$ is an element of the complement, so such a $U$ exists.  And Pere didn't say $f$ is the identity on $S^2\setminus U$, just that it has a fixed point on this set.

Comment: Oh right, yes I definitely overlooked that! Thank you.